# iterating through a linkedhashmap but over a certain range

Tags: java, iteration, linkedhashmap

So i know how to iterate through a whole linkedhashmap from the beginning, but what if I want to only link through a certain portion from it? IE: i want to start from the end and go only 4 elements back. How would I do that and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which would allow you to iterate backwards in a list. Unfortunately, `LinkedHashMap` does not hold a reference towards the previous element, and thus does not provide this iterator.

So, you end up with two solutions. One, you implement the method to find the X last elements: you hold, let's say an array (a circular buffer) of size X and keep there the last X elements you have seen. This solution is rather inefficient if you call this method frequently and for X much smaller than the size of your map.

A second solution is to keep a `HashMap` instead of a `LinkedHashMap` and an extra `List` to maintain the insertion order. E.g. an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` which provide a `ListIterator` and thus, backwards iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend standard implementation and override methods that return appropriate iterator to your own.

```
Iterator<K> newKeyIterator()   { return new KeyIterator();   }
Iterator<V> newValueIterator() { return new ValueIterator(); }
Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> newEntryIterator() { return new EntryIterator(); }
```

`LinkedHashMap.Entry` is a doubly linked list, so you can go forward and backward as well.
`LinkedHashMap.LinkedHashIterator` is a base iterator for LinkedHashMap. Make what you need based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for this, by doing something like this.

```
List list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
ListIterator li = list.listIterator(list.size());
while (li.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(li.previous()));
}
```

Since the `LinkedHashMap` maintains the order, you could simply create a list from the keys which are going to be in order as well. Get a `ListIterator` from the last index, so that you can traverse backwards having a counter(which I've not shown) to iterator till the no. of elements required.